# Anchor Text inside an image element even when image shrunk or cropped by the window

Tags: javascript, html, css

**TEST OUT THE ISSUE HERE: https://jsfiddle.net/dmpqubsz/2/ and via Stack Snippet**

- You'll need to scroll down in the viewport once you have run the code to show the image (it's added on `.addEventListener('wheel'`))

**Issue: I want to display Text over an Image but it to behave as if it were part of the image**. And as such it needs to scale in the same way I've built my Image to scale. i.e It retains it's aspect ratio and will either crop in or enlarge the image to fit the Viewport Window.

Example: Say I wanted the text to appear on a certain cloud in the Image. Right now when I change the Window/Screen Size it won't scale with the image and will float elsewhere.

TLDR: Render Text over Image, keeping it's relative position and size consistent. Image crops and changes size.

**Why I'm Stuck:** I can't find a reliable way to correlate the text to the Image via CSS without very convoluted JS. I have searched online and asked Bings ChatGPT competitor.

**Info:** The Image follows a few rules, `object-position: center bottom`, `object-fit: cover` and `height: 100%` primarily. Please find Stack Snippet below with the entire code:

As you can probably tell, quite new to raw CSS powered Web-Dev.

```js
const imageContainer = document.querySelector('.image-container');
const imagePaths = [ // All the images that are stacked, share the same dimensions & sizing rules
    "https://images.theconversation.com/files/393210/original/file-20210401-13-z6rl6z.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&rect=0%2C292%2C3008%2C1504&q=45&auto=format&w=1356&h=668&fit=crop",
    "images/2_Background.png",
    "images/3_Dog.png",
    "images/4_Chair.png",
    "images/5_Teddy.png",
    "images/6_Flask.png",
    "images/7_Pen.png",
    "images/8_Theo.png",
];

let currentIndex = -1;
let currentObject = null

const textOverlay = document.querySelector(".text-overlay")
const imageText = [ // This will eventually
    "images/1_NightSky.png",
    "images/2_Background.png",
    "images/3_Dog.png",
    "images/4_Chair.png",
    "images/5_Teddy.png",
    "images/6_Flask.png",
    "images/7_Pen.png",
    "images/8_Theo.png",
]

function updateText(imageNumber) {

}

function addImageToContainer(imagePath) {
    const imageLayer = document.createElement('div');
    imageLayer.classList.add('image-layer');

    const image = document.createElement('img');
    image.classList.add('image');

    image.src = imagePath;
    image.alt = 'Layered Image';

    imageLayer.appendChild(image);
    imageContainer.appendChild(imageLayer);

    currentObject = imageLayer
}

function addNewImage(imageNumber) {
    if (imageNumber < imagePaths.length) {
        addImageToContainer(imagePaths[imageNumber]);
        updateExistingImage()
    }
}

function updateExistingImage() {
    let indexDecimal = currentIndex / 100
    let newOpacity = indexDecimal - Math.floor(indexDecimal)

    currentObject.style.opacity = newOpacity
    console.log(newOpacity)

}


document.addEventListener('wheel', event => {
    let lastIndex = currentIndex

    if (event.deltaY > 0) {
        currentIndex++
    } else {
        //currentIndex--
    }

    let lastImage = Math.floor(lastIndex / 100)
    let currentImage = Math.floor(currentIndex / 100) // + 1

    if (lastImage !== currentImage) {
        addNewImage(currentImage)
    } else {
        if (currentImage >=imagePaths.length) {
            return
        }
        updateExistingImage()
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif; /* font-family: 'Amita', cursive; /* font-family: Arial, sans-serif; */
    background-color: #1f1f36; /* Replace with the desired color code */
}

.image-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh; /* Set the height to control the scrolling area */
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image-layer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1; /* Start with images hidden */
    /* transition: opacity 0.5s ease; */
    z-index: 1; /* Increase this value for each subsequent layer */
}

.image-layer img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; /*height: auto;*/
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center bottom;
}

.text-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: calc(20% + (50% - 50vh)); /* Adjust as needed */
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Semi-transparent background for readability */
  }
  
  .text-overlay h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  .text-overlay p {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amita:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amita:wght@700&family=Kanit:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Layered Images</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="image-container">
        <div class="image-layer" style="z-index: 2;">
            <img class = "image" style="image-rendering: pixelated;" src="images/ScrollDown.png" alt="Layered Image">
            <div class="text-overlay">
                <h1>Theo Docking</h1>
                <p>Game Developer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Images will be added dynamically with JavaScript -->
    </div>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to position the text relative to the full image. Please  make your code into a runnable snippet within the question not on an external site. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth I have updated my post to include a Stack Snippet, thank you for alerting me to their existance. I had scanned existing topics and saw jsfiddle used on occasion and obviously got the wrong idea. Would really appreciate a more complete answer if you have the time now more context is available via the snippet. Thanks again.

Comment: Please limit your code to just enough to replicate the problem. Is the dynamic addition of the elements on scroll necessary or part of the problem? If not remove them , it makes it easier to identify the actual problem. Make it as easy as possible for us to help you.

Comment: As @JonP has suggested, please cut down code to show just the problem in the question. One way to do this is to use your browser devtools inspect facility to see the actual HTML and CSS in use on an img and its text. Copy and paste that to create the snippet. (Don’t give just the screenshot image). Also put some actual images in there that we can see,  otherwise the snippet won’t show the problem.